# How to check for Html or any other format getting as an input?

Tags: javascript, java

If user is entering normal string, I need not to convert it to Xml format.. If I get Html data, then I have to convert into Xml. How can I check that without using Regex?

Comment: It is hard to be 100% sure if a user enters HTML or plain text, especially using regexp. A better option is probably to first ask the user what he/she will enter, then handle input accordingly.

Comment: yourString.contains("<HTML>") ?

Comment: User will enter a normal string only, but the text area will convert that into Html.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/2506522
"Have you tried using an XML parser instead?"

Comment: Java != JavaScript, but you've tagged them both.  Which language are you asking about?

Comment: I am asking for both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

`Html` and `Xml` always Starts with  `<` Tag. the simplest without regex way of checking if it not Start with `<` then it is normal `String`. Otherwise If it start with `<` then it may be normal String or HTML too.

And `Html` contains `<html>` Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function

```
function isHTML(str) {
     var a = document.createElement('div');
     a.innerHTML = str;

     for (var c = a.childNodes, i = c.length; i--; ) {
     if (c[i].nodeType == 1) return true; 
     }
    return false;
}
```